# MVC Viewmodel cant access model with View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How can I access my viewmodel from my view?  my code is as follows:-,

I have two models (using entity framework) which have a view model of:-

```
 public class ViewModelStory
{
    public IEnumerable<tbl_GCB_NewsItem> GCB_NewsItem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tbl_GCB_ItemComment> comemnts { get; set; }

}
```

My contoller populates the models by:-

```
        ViewModelStory.GCB_NewsItem = (from i in db.tbl_GCB_NewsItem
                    where i.intItemIdentifier.ToString() == StoryId
                    select i).SingleOrDefault();

        ViewModelStory.comemnts = (from i in db.tbl_GCB_ItemComment
                                       where i.intItemIdentifier.ToString() == StoryId
                                       select i).ToList<tbl_GCB_ItemComment>();
```

I return the model by

```
      return PartialView("NewsStory", ViewModelStory);
```

then in my view I have the following declaration

```
@model ViewModelStory
@using GCBSMVC.Models
```

To access my model I have tried  various from Linq to and directly querying the model, but nothing seems to work:- 
    Html.DisplayFor(m =>m.GCB_NewsItem. ....
    ViewModelStory.GCB_NewsItem.strItemCategory
    Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewModelStory.GCB_NewsItem.strItemHeadline))

Comment: What does the return value of your controller action look like? Do you populate the view to return correctly, e.g return View("myView", myModel)?

Comment: I return it by :  return PartialView("NewsStory", ViewModelStory);  i shall also update the question forgot to add this bit.

Comment: I m afraid but you can't set ViewModelStory.GCB_NewsItem properties this way. Please make an object and then set properties. if your object has same name as class, please change it and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the type of you model class instead of the actual class. Try this:

```
var model = new ViewModelStory();
model.GCB_NewsItem = (from i in db.tbl_GCB_NewsItem
                    where i.intItemIdentifier.ToString() == StoryId
                    select i).SingleOrDefault();

model.comemnts = (from i in db.tbl_GCB_ItemComment
                                       where i.intItemIdentifier.ToString() == StoryId
                                       select i).ToList<tbl_GCB_ItemComment>();

return PartialView("NewsStory", model);
```